# Why don't we say al hanissim in al hamichya?

Tags: chanuka, purim, al-hanissim, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

Al hanissim (על הניסים) is a short addition to shemoneh esrei and birkas hamazon on Chanukah and Purim; however, there is no corresponding bit that's added to al hamichya, unlike retzei (for Shabbos) and yaaleh veyavo (for yamim tovim and rosh chodesh).

Why is that?